# Use non-default Laravel 4.2 Queue Connection

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, queue

I need to swap out the Laravel Queue connection when I queue certain items.

E.g. default is `redis` but I need to swap it out to use `sqs` when I queue certain items.

Is there anyway to do this without having to change the default queue connection using `Config::set('queue.default', 'sqs');`?

I notice it's easy to specify which queue name to use by passing it as a third argument to `Queue:push()`, but this only let's you change the queue name, not the queue connection itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Queue::connection` to swith to another **connection**.

```
Queue::connection('new-connection')->push('QueueClass@queueMethod', [], 'queue-name');
```